# How to align the rotation of an instance to object normals?

Tags: normals, geometry-nodes, geometry, instances

I am having trouble with Geometry Nodes in Blender. Basically, I'm trying to create some cables that have additional instantiated objects at the ends. I want the rotation of these objects to be aligned with a cube, but I can't get it to work.
The alignment does not match the normals of the cube. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

here is my geometry nodes

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 1):

You have done everything right so far, the setup already fits!

However, the reference of the positions does not match.

In short, both objects (your curve and your cube) need the same origin/reference point.

Either you set the *Location* of your curve to the position $(0, 0, 0)$, or you don't use the *original* position for your cube with the node `Object Info`, but a *relative* position.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>